# abstract method not implemented in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I added some feature to an existing running project and I tested the Application full testing after that to find out that any RecyclerView crashes after add/removing items from it ( after notifying the adapter with the changes ).

I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I tried to use `notifyItemRemoved()` and `notifyItemInserted()` but the problem still happening.

My gradle file :

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
        .......
        .......
```

The Logs :

```
08-29 09:48:21.874: W/dalvikvm(4290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d29b20)
08-29 09:48:21.874: W/System.err(4290): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java:3252)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$700(RecyclerView.java:147)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processDisappeared(RecyclerView.java:431)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:246)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3098)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2917)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
08-29 09:48:21.884: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1191)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 09:48:21.894: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-29 09:48:21.904: W/System.err(4290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: put some part of recyclerview or code you changed.

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractMethodError` is a dual exception (has both cases of being caught at compile time and cases of being caught at runtime) . And Java docs for this class states "Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.".

Abstract methods are function without implementation i.e. they only have defined function signature (a.k.a. header) . So when JVM jumps to an abstract method's entry point, it throws this exception since it doesn't know what to do (function definition is still empty) . So you need to override all abstract functions defined in the class you're extending with actual functions that have implementation. In your case in particular, `RecyclerView` calls abstract function [animateDissapearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#animateDisappearance(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo)) when removing an item from its adapter's collection, and it also calls abstract function [animateAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#animateAppearance(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo)) when adding an item to its adapter's collection. You don't seem to be overriding these functions in your RecyclerView class.

The fix to your exception ends with the previous paragraph. This is just in case you're wondering why would anyone use abstract methods when they don't do anything and even cause exceptions.

Abstract methods (mostly used in libraries and other developer tools) allow the developer to reference, schedule and work with arbitrarily complex unit of work without worrying about its actual implementation. This is especially useful when you're developing libraries since you don't know the cases your users are going to use. I'll give an example that people can, hopefully, easily identify with:

Imagine you are developing a tool that want to support plugins developed by independent developers. To have an even clearer example - let it be an email client. Now, we'll take a look at one situation when your email client should send the email. And suppose you're expecting dev community to develop plugins that backup email copies to hard drive, to cloud storage or any other action that is related to the mail, prior to the sending. You don't and can't know what they are up to, but you know what they need as input and expect at output. So you implement your mail-sending function like this:

```
boolean sendMail(HashMap<String, String> headers, String body, String recipient, List<DeveloperPlugin> activePlugins) {
    //Your parameter validation
    for(DeveloperPlugin plugin : activePlugins) {
        plugin.runBeforeSendEmailAction(headers, body);
    }
    //Send email
}
```

Then you instruct your developer community to store all their logic in a class that extends `DeveloperPlugin` class (or implements `DeveloperPlugin` interface) and specifically implement all their actions related to mail that they want to execute before the mail is actually sent, inside the `runBeforeSendEmailAction(HashMap<String, String> headers, String body)` function of that class (interface) . This solves the biggest problem you face as main module developer - how to ensure application behaves the same no matter what plugin developers implement. It also solves the biggest problem plugin developers face - how do I know what input will my function get and how and when do I call it?

I considerably went overboard with this, but hopefully someone will find it interesting, maybe even helpful.

Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downgrade the `android support` libraries to `23.1.1` and disabling the change animations :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

And in the activity class :

```
      //Added the following line just for case
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
      //REMOVE the following line
      recyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);
```

In the `XML` add the following line to the `RecycleView` tag :

```
     android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

And eveything is working fine with me now.